# React-native Redux Component not re-rendering on state change with boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm unable to get my component to re-render once I've called an action and updated my store with my reducer. The actual problem is that I cannot get my modal component to appear once I've clicked a button.

The state updates properly. I'm able to see that the boolean value I have in the store is changing from `false` to `true`, but it's not updating my component with the new information. Here's some code below:

```
// Home Page

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ModalComponent from '../components/modal.component';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleShowModal } from '../actions/modal-actions';

class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    // some values
    showModal: false,
  };

  // added on edit
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps !== this.props) {
      this.setState({
        showModal: nextProps.showModal, 
      })
    }
  }

  _toggleModalVisibility = () => {
    // redux action
    this.props.toggleShowModal();
  }

  render() {
    <ModalComponent isVisible={this.state.showModal} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    showModal: state.showModal,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ toggleShowModal }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

```
// Actions

import { SHOW_MODAL } from './types';

export const toggleShowModal = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: SHOW_MODAL,
    showModal: true,
  });
};
```

```
// Reducers (reducers are combined in another file and work fine)

import { SHOW_MODAL } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  showModal: false,
};

export const modalReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        showModal: action.showModal,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

What seems to happen is the store is updated with `showModal: true`, but it doesn't translate to the view. The code above is just an example because the project is pretty large and overwhelming. I have other pieces in Redux working just fine, for some reason this is not working for me.

[Here's a short video on what's happening in my live app](https://youtu.be/Jw-4Xz62y7I) It seems like the state changes, but doesn't update the view until I do something like try and scroll up on the `FlatList` on that page.

Comment: have you used combinereducers?

Comment: I mean do you . have multiple reducers?

Comment: @Sarmad Yes I do have a file combining reducers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I figured out that I wasn't exporting my reducers correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    showModal: state.showModal,
  };
};
```

As I see in the above code, You are using `state.showModal` to get the showModal variable, well you can't 
as you have used an object in your reducers, 
So it shall be something like

```
return {
    showModal: state.reducerName.showModal,
  };
```

Where reducerName is the reducer key you have used inside combineReducers

One more thing, Your componentWillReceiveProps logic won't work too, 
as you are comparing two objects.

I would recommend you to use `componentDidUpdate()` as cWRP is not recommended. and also check compare this.props.showModel instead of this.props. 
for example

`this.props.showModal !== nextProps.showModal`
You can read more about object equality here

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Comment: You're right, this is what I get for writing example code. In my real project, it is using the reducer name. Other parts of redux work fine, even on this component.

Comment: It would be better if you show your real code, not all of it. But don't post the wrong code as it can be misleading.

Comment: I forget that CWRP is not used anymore. I did make those changes, but I'm still running into the same problem. I posted a small edit video to get a better feel of what it's looking like when using the app.